# Rsync creates a directory with the same name inside of destination directory

Tags: rsync

When I run this command

```
rsync -avzp --del -e "ssh -p myport" user@hostname:/var/www/tests /var/www/tests
```

files get synchronized but instead of saving files in `/var/www/tests`, Rsync creates one more directory "tests" inside of existing "tests":

```
/var/www/tests/tests
```

and puts files there. How to tell Rsync not to create a new directory?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you don't want another `tests` directory created, the correct command would be

```
rsync -avzp --del -e "ssh -p myport" user@hostname:/var/www/tests/ /var/www/tests
```

Note the `/` at the end of `user@hostname:/var/www/tests/`.

Comment: beware also of the rsync option -R, if you are having this problem. The very purpose of -R (or --relative) is to recreate the full source directory path at the destination. So it will have the same effect as if you omit the trailing slash.

Comment: `-a` already contains `-p`

Answer (score 42):

**You need a trailing slash on the source.**

Here is the correct command:

```
rsync -avzp --del -e "ssh -p myport" user@hostname:/var/www/tests/ /var/www/tests
```

#### More Info

Explanation of rsync and trailing slashes:

http://defindit.com/readme_files/rsync_backup.html

> Rsync has two major modes of operation. The modes are dependent on the
>   absence or presence of the trailing slash on the source directory.

Another example:

http://www.jveweb.net/en/archives/2010/11/synchronizing-folders-with-rsync.html

> ...you need to add the trailing slash, otherwise, a folder called
>   Pictures is created inside the Pictures folder that we specify as
>   destination.